# Converting XML to a flat file

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have a requirement where I have to get an XML file from an IFS and put it to a flat file.
The flat file should be loaded exactly as the XML data is
For Example, if the XML is

```xml
<Employee>
    <FirstName>JIM</FirstName>
    <LastName>SMITH</LastName>
    <EmpAddress>
        <StreetName>DARTMOUTH WAY</StreetName>
        <STATE>OHIO</STATE>
    </EmpAddress>
    <EmpAddress>
        <StreetName>SouthRidge Road</StreetName>
        <STATE>WA</STATE>
    </EmpAddress>
    <PreviousCompany>
        <CompName>DELL</CompName>
        <CompAddress>
        <StreetName>Road123</StreetName>
        <STATE>WA</STATE>
        </CompAddress>
    <PreviousCompany>
<Employee>
```

then the flt file data should be

```
JIM SMITH
DARTMOUTH WAY OHIO
SouthRidge Road WA
DELL 
Road123 WA
```

So basically each segment of the XML should be a single record in the flat File. But any of the segment (like `EmpAddress` or `PreviousCompany` or `CompAddress`) can repeat multiple times. So flat file should have it in the same order.

I did think of XML-INTO as well as XMLTABLE but I could not get a easy solution.

Please let me know if there is a easy to implement solution for this.

Comment: Uh, _why_?  Normally I'd prefer the "entityness" of the XML (assuming I can process it as XML, instead of a raw text file), especially as it makes telling where one entity starts and other ends.  For one thing, what happens if there's a different number of addresses, how do you tell?  Note that SQL is a poor fit, because this isn't going to be presented as the set of rows you're looking for.

Comment: The reason we want it in this format is that, there is already a process which takes a flat file(which is got from a outside system as FTP) and does the underlying processes. Now they have changed this to XML. So I just need to make the XML into a Flat file so that all the underlying process remains the same.  The way I have decided to achieve this is to create multiple Temp tables for each segments. That table will also contain the Keys of higher segments. By this way, I can create the relationships between different segments.

Comment: How would your process know that `SouthRidge Road WA` is an address and not the next employee name?

Comment: Infact, each row in the flat file will have the segment name as well(at the beginning). I just removed it from here as I dint want to complicate it here. Thanks!

Comment: ....you're just complicating things.  Adding an extra step adds an extra point of failure.  Assuming the original code was reasonably written (...which might not be true...), you'd probably do as much work trying to write the XML-to-flatfile as just converting the original flatfile process.  For one thing, if you're trying to get this into a database, you can more directly import it (via `XMLTABLE`).  What does your original process do?

Comment: I agree with @Clockwork-Muse on this one.  This is one of those things that seems like a good idea at first but ends up being a maintenance nightmare as things go on.  It's almost certainly better to just convert the original programs to use the new XML file rather than run this conversion.  The only time I think you would do it the way you ask is if you don't have source code access to the original programs.

Comment: You can convert and XML to a CSV by running and XSLT over the file.  Sometimes XSLT can make things easier to interface with an older system.  Sometimes XSLT can make things even more difficult to maintain.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT

Answer (score 0):

`XML-INTO` is about as easy as it gets. Build a data structure to receive the data, and then process the data out of the data structure in whatever way you want. The key is to give `XML-INTO` a way to tell you how many of each loop constructs exist, or if there are missing elements. Here is an example which could work for your Employee XML:

```
// v7.3+
dcl-ds Employee         Qualified;
  FirstName             Varchar(64);
  LastName              Varchar(64);
  dcl-ds EmpAddress     Qualified Dim(10);
    StreetName          Varchar(64);
    State               Varchar(32);
  end-ds;
  countEmpAddress       Int(10);
  dcl-ds PreviousCompany  Qualified Dim(10);
    CompanyName         Varchar(64);
    dcl-ds CompAddress  Qualified Dim(10);
      StreetName        Varchar(64);
      State             Varchar(64);
    end-ds;
    countCompAddress    Int(10);
  end-ds;
  countPreviousCompany  Int(10);
end-ds;

// Pre v7.3
dcl-ds Employee         Qualified;
  FirstName             Varchar(64);
  LastName              Varchar(64);
  EmpAddress            LikeDs(address_t) Dim(10);
  countEmpAddress       Int(10);
  PreviousCompany       LikeDs(company_t) Dim(10);
  countPreviousCompany  Int(10);
end-ds;

dcl-ds company_t        Qualified Template;
  CompanyName           Varchar(64);
  CompAddress           LikeDs(address_t) Dim(10);
  countCompAddress      Int(10);
end-ds;

dcl-ds address_t        Qualified Template;
  StreetName            Varchar(64);
  State                 Varchar(64);
end-ds;
```

To use `XML-INTO` to load the data into this structure, you simply use:

```
xml-into Employee %xml('employee.xml': 'doc=file countprefix=count +
    case=any allowmissing=yes');
```

More info can be found in the IBM documentation here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzasd/allowmissopt.htm

Comment: Thanks for Explanation Mark!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the Valuable Suggestions!

The way I did was as below:

I created a temp table with all the elements in the XML as Fields. By having this Temp table, I knew which segment is under which segment (each segment had a distinct key). I wrote each segment to a flat file (each segment and the higher segments for that will be populated. Rest will be Null) by using XMLTABLE. Now, I wrote a RPG Program having multiple cursors for the repeating segments and doing group By's.

So first the RPG program would read the Highest segment, then go one level down and read that segment with they key of the higher segment and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same using `AWK` and `sed`. Below are the codes:

```
#Removing blank line from the actual file using sed.

sed -r '/^\s*$/d' Employee >Employee1

Employee.awk

BEGIN { FS ="[></]";RS ="\n\n"; OFS =""}
$0 ~ search {print $5 "\t"$10,"\n"$17 "\t" $22,"\n"$32 "\t" $37,"\n"$47,"\n"$54 "\t" $59}

awk -f Employee.awk Employee1
```

Output:

```
JIM SMITH

DARTMOUTH WAY   OHIO

SouthRidge Road WA

DELL

Road123 WA
```